# EOF when reading user input after reading from stdin

Tags: python, file, command-line-interface, stdin

I have the following python script which should optionally read text piped from stdin and appends it to a string, then enter a loop where it receives user input until the 'Q' character is read.

```
import sys

def read_text_from_stdin():
    if sys.stdin.isatty() or not sys.stdin.readable():
        return None
    text = sys.stdin.read().strip()
    return text if text else None

def get_user_input():
    print('Write input or [Q]uit: ', end='')
    try:
        user_input = input()
        return user_input
    except EOFError as e:
        raise e


def main():
    stdin = read_text_from_stdin()
    user_input = f"Test {stdin}" if stdin else 'Test'
    first_input = True

    while True:
        action = user_input if first_input else get_user_input()
        first_input = False

        if action == 'Q':
            sys.exit(0)
        elif action == '':
            pass
        else:
            print(action)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run the script `python input_test.py` without stdin piped then it operates as expected.

If I run the script `cat input_test.py | python input_test.py` then it prints out the stdin content appended to the 'Test' string, but then hits an EOF when reading the line for the user input. I presume the EOF is left on the stdin buffer after the stdin is read the first time, so all subsequent reads with `input` fail due to this, but is there a way around this? Can I write something to stdin or flush it out?

Comment: If you write `cat ... | python`, then the stdin for the python script is the output of `cat`.  It is not the case that "EOF is left on the stdin buffer", it is simply that `cat` has terminated and closed the pipe.  There is *no* association between the python process' `stdin` and the `tty` in which your shell was running when it spawned the pipeline.  "user input" is in no way associated with python's stdin.  Stop thinking of stdin as the user's keyboard.

Comment: If you want python to read from a tty, then you need to explicitly read from a tty.  But a shortcut to perhaps solve your immediate issue is to do: `cat input_test.py - | python ...`, so `cat` will read from the tty and pass the data to python. (But this will fail since your python script explicitly checks if its input is a tty; you could omit that check.)